# How to push to GitHub after amend

Tags: git, github

I commited my file and pushed to GitHub. But I forgot to add my HTML file. So I used `git commit --amend` to amend my commit. But now how can I resolve my mistake on GitHub?

Comment: you can try to squash commit `git reset --soft HEAD~1` than `add` all files and commit again, this will override your last commit

Comment: git push --force-with-lease

Comment: @JB Nizet sorry I did not see your comment before posting my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @Yoginth, you might do `git push --force`, but it is better (because safer) to do `git push --force-with-lease` instead.

The corresponding syntax is described in this handy [list of git tips](https://github.com/git-tips/tips#forced-push-but-still-ensure-you-dont-overwrite-others-work):

```
git push --force-with-lease <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

To be more precise, [git push --force-with-lease](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-force-with-lease) will refuse to force-push if the *remote* branch (say, branch `master` in repo `origin`) has commits that are unknown in *local* branch `origin/master`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `push --force` command to force push over the old commit.

```
git push --force example-branch
```

https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/

Answer (score -2):

All that said, have in mind that amending a commits previously pushed is a bad practice (bad bad), and it is only safe to do in the case of the branch you're pushing is only yours and not a shared one.

If someone else pulls from that branch, it could lead to conflicts, and lots of unexpected situations such as:

- Conflicted merges
- Overritten changes
- Headache
- Joint pain
- Global warming